# how to get ip from users logged into a machine

Tags: ruby, unix, command

I'm writting a shell in ruby and I need to know if there's a way to get the IP from users logged to a machine. I know that the command `who` can do that but I can't fetch its output into a variable. Can someone give me an idea? I'm lost!

Comment: Why can't you store it in a variable?

Comment: `your_var = %x!who!`.